# How can I convince Gmail to archive messages that I've sent?

Tags: gmail

When you send a message from Gmail (I usually use cntrl+enter or do it from Mailbox) it appears in your inbox. Is it possible to create a label or use something similar to automatically archive sent messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way to archive the sent mail in Gmail. How to create the filter:

Go to `settings` in Gmail.

[image]

Go to the `Filters` tab and select `Create a new filter`.

[image]

Enter your email address in the `From` section and proceed by selecting `Create filter with this search`.

[image]

Now tick `Skip the inbox (Archive it)` and also tick `Apply the label` and select `New label` 
[image]

Create a name for the label like Sent_Archive
[image]

Proceed with `Create Filter`
[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me, in that it did apply the label, but did not move the messages out of the Sent Mail folder.